# Strange linking behavior, latest g++

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++

I have been running into strange linking behavior with g++, however, I'm just a student, and I was wondering if this was normal.

I am trying to link assembly code (machine: fedora 14 gnome 32bits x86 i686 intel i7) with c++ code and to have the assembly code call a method from a fonction instanciated in the c++ file. It seems that implementing a method in the class declaration will prevent it from being put in the linker table unless it's used at least once in the original source.

```
class A
{
public:
    void showSUP() {
        cout<<"sup";
    }
};
```

After instanciating `A`, you will not be able to call `_ZN1A7showSUPEv` because it has not been put in the linking table:

```
call _ZN1A7showSUPEv
```

However, if you call A::showSUP() in the same .cpp as `A` was declared, then calling it from a seperate assembly file will work.

With (and instantiation of `A`)

```
class A
{
    void showSUP();
};

A::showSUP()
{
    cout<<"sup";
}
```

Calling `_ZN1A7showSUPEv` will work.

My question is, why doesn't the first example work.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Sounds like your compiler is omitting unused functions. A quick Googling though looks like -Wunused-function will warn against this, but nothing about omitting. Weird.

Comment: i guess that the function definition inside the class is inlined.

Comment: @wjlafrance: No, it's not weird. With little bit of understanding, it should be expected. Since the function is defined inside the class declaration, it's definition will clearly be available when compiling any use of it and it's definition may be seen by the compiler in multiple modules. Since compilation of different modules is independent, the compiler can't tell whether it will get the compiled code from another module and has to generate it in all of them and merge them during linking. To avoid wasting resources, it's only generated where used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For inlined functions the compiler
  will only output code where the function is used.
- Functions defined
  inside the class definition are
  inline (usually).
- The function isn't
  used.
- Therefore: no function in the
  binary.

Comment: Functions defined inside the class definition behave as if specified with `inline` modifier by specification, not usually (they don't have to end up always inlined though, because it's not always possible or reasonable).

Comment: So, @Julius, no, it's not specific to gcc. All C++ compilers behave that way. They have to. A function defined inside class body will certainly be available in all modules using it and none of the modules can be selected as the place to generate them. So they have to be generated in all modules that use it (generating it in all modules that see it would be very wasteful of resources) and the instances merged during linking. Side-effect is that if it's never used or if all instances get inlined, no symbol is generated for it at all.

Comment: @Jan: Yes you are right. By (usually) I meant that they are usually actually inlined. Inlined as in having no separate function call/return.

Comment: Even if inlined, as in code actually being inserted at the place of call, many times compilers will also generate a separate symbol at least after the first use. The reason being that the standard guarantees that you can take the address of the function (incidentally that the address of the function will be unique in the program, so it is a weak symbol so that the linker can discard all but one copies) Again, this is a detail of implementation.

Answer (score 5):

There are attributes, that you can specifify for a function in this way

```
classe A
{
  public:
    void showSUP(){
      cout<<"sup";
    } __attribute__((used))
};
```

see [gcc attribute overview](http://www.ohse.de/uwe/articles/gcc-attributes.html#func-used)

> used
>       Found in versions: 3.1-3.4 
>       Description:
>
> ```
>      This attribute, attached to a function, means that code must be
>      emitted for the function even if it appears that the function is
>      not referenced.  This is useful, for example, when the function
> ```
>
> is
>            referenced only in inline assembly.

Comment: your answer and Zan's together are perfect.
Thank you so much for introducing me to gcc's attributes.

Comment: @Julius: one note, attributes are usually compiler specific. If you're already dabbling with assembly you are already tied to some platforms, but this is another dependence to think of.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you want a function to be included in the final library / executable, it need be:

- used
- non-inlined

And `inlined` function is a function whose code is simply copied and pasted where the function is used (by the compiler) so that there is no function call. It's an opportunity optimization, so a function may be inlined in some places and not inlined in others, depending on the context. Most very short functions (so-called one-liners) are generally inlined.

In the old times, to be inlined a function needed be defined in the current translation unit, that is:

- either it is defined in the header (like is your case), and thus can be inlined in all sources including this header
- either it is defined in a source file, and thus can be inlined in *this* source file

Nowadays though we also have LTO (Link Time Optimization), and if activated the linker may actually inline function calls. Those optimizations are also responsible for cleaning up the resulting library/binary from *unused* symbols.

There are two possible solutions to your issue:

- define the function in a source file instead, it is standard and may not be wiped out
- use compiler specific attributes to mark the function as used, so that it's not wiped out

In the latter case, if you wish for portability, I can only advise using a macro (`ATTRIBUTE_USED`) and define its content depending on the current compiler used.